# opengl program crashes on glBegin(GL_QUADS)

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, textures, render

I have this program you can see below. The program should render something to a texture, and the rendered texture should be drawn to display. But the program fails at the display() function, when calling glBegin(GL_QUADS). The program ends printing

```
ElectricFence Aborting: free(96f110): address not from malloc().
Ungültiger Maschinenbefehl (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

In english this should mean something like

```
invalid machine command (dump written)
```

.

```
#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GL/glext.h"
#include "GL/glu.h"
#include "GL/glut.h"

#include <cstdio>

uint16_t tex_width = 75;
uint16_t tex_height = 24;

GLuint texture;

void render_texture()
{
   GLuint framebuffer = 0;

   glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
   glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

   glGenTextures(1, &texture);

   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, tex_width, tex_height, 0, GL_RGBA,
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

   glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
   GLenum draw_buffers[1] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
   glDrawBuffers(1, draw_buffers);

   if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
   {  
      fprintf(stderr, "[render_texture] Fehler im Framebuffer\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
   glViewport(0, 0, tex_width, tex_height);

   glColor4f(0.8f, 0.0f, 0.8f, 0.5f);

   glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
   glVertex2f(0.f,0.f);
   glVertex2f(tex_width, 0.0f);
   glVertex2f(tex_width, (GLfloat)tex_height/2.f);
   glVertex2f(tex_width-(GLfloat)tex_height/2.f, tex_height);
   glVertex2f(0, tex_height);
   glEnd();
}

void display(void)
{
   glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
   glViewport(0, 0, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH), glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT));

   glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT/* | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT*/);

   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glPushMatrix();
   glLoadIdentity();
   glOrtho(0.0, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH), 0.0, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT), -1.0, 1.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glPushMatrix();

   glLoadIdentity();

   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);


   // Draw a textured quad
   glBegin(GL_QUADS);
   glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
   glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(0, tex_width, 0);
   glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(tex_height, tex_width, 0);
   glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(tex_height, 0, 0);
   glEnd();


   glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   glPopMatrix();


   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glPopMatrix();

   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);


   glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

   glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE/* | GLUT_DEPTH*/);
   glutInitWindowSize(1024, 1024);
   glutCreateWindow("texture copy test");
   glutDisplayFunc(display);

   glewInit();

   render_texture();

   glutMainLoop();
}
```

I have compiled the code with following command

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -std=c++11 -lpng -lGL -lglut -lGLEW  -lGLU -lefence -g
```

gdb tells me that
[rejak@localhost src]$ gdb ./test
    GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
    Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
    This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
    There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
    and "show warranty" for details.
    This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".
    For bug reporting instructions, please see:
    http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/...
    Reading symbols from /home/rejak/projects/glwidgets/src/test...done.
    (gdb) run
    Starting program: /home/rejak/projects/glwidgets/src/./test 
    warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffa000
    warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1.
    Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
    [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
    Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".

```
ElectricFence Aborting: free(769110): address not from malloc().

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x00007ffff645c6c7 in kill () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) q
A debugging session is active.

        Inferior 1 [process 1350] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
[rejak@localhost src]$ gdb ./test
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1                                                                                                                  
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.                                                                                    
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>                                                        
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.                                                                   
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"                                                           
and "show warranty" for details.                                                                                                     
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".                                                                               
For bug reporting instructions, please see:                                                                                          
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...                                                                                           
Reading symbols from /home/rejak/projects/glwidgets/src/test...done.                                                                 
(gdb) run                                                                                                                            
Starting program: /home/rejak/projects/glwidgets/src/./test                                                                          
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffa000                                       
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1.                                                                  
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?                                                                                
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]                                                                                        
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".                                                                        

ElectricFence Aborting: free(769110): address not from malloc().                                                                     

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.                                                                                 
0x00007ffff645c6c7 in kill () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6                                                                                
(gdb) bt full                                                                                                                        
#0  0x00007ffff645c6c7 in kill () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6                                                                            
No symbol table info available.                                                                                                      
#1  0x00007ffff6ff14ad in ?? () from /usr/lib/libefence.so.0                                                                         
No symbol table info available.                                                                                                      
#2  0x00007ffff6ff18c7 in EF_Abortv () from /usr/lib/libefence.so.0                                                                  
No symbol table info available.                                                                                                      
#3  0x00007ffff6ff1968 in EF_Abort () from /usr/lib/libefence.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007ffff6ff0eda in free () from /usr/lib/libefence.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00007ffff2a53e68 in _mesa_align_realloc () from /usr/lib/libdricore9.2.0.so.1
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00007ffff2bced4c in _mesa_add_parameter () from /usr/lib/libdricore9.2.0.so.1
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x00007ffff2bceefa in _mesa_add_state_reference () from /usr/lib/libdricore9.2.0.so.1
No symbol table info available.
#8  0x00007ffff2fedb29 in ?? () from /usr/lib/xorg/modules/dri/i965_dri.so
No symbol table info available.
#9  0x00007ffff2bc4882 in _mesa_glsl_link_shader () from /usr/lib/libdricore9.2.0.so.1
No symbol table info available.
#10 0x00007ffff2a38c33 in _mesa_get_fixed_func_fragment_program () from /usr/lib/libdricore9.2.0.so.1
No symbol table info available.
#11 0x00007ffff2a86f68 in _mesa_update_state_locked () from /usr/lib/libdricore9.2.0.so.1
No symbol table info available.
#12 0x00007ffff2a87041 in _mesa_update_state () from /usr/lib/libdricore9.2.0.so.1
No symbol table info available.
#13 0x00007ffff2ac5a08 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libdricore9.2.0.so.1
No symbol table info available.
#14 0x0000000000401675 in display () at test.cpp:75
No locals.
#15 0x00007ffff7720ac4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libglut.so.3
No symbol table info available.
#16 0x00007ffff7724329 in fgEnumWindows () from /usr/lib/libglut.so.3
No symbol table info available.
#17 0x00007ffff772107d in glutMainLoopEvent () from /usr/lib/libglut.so.3
No symbol table info available.
#18 0x00007ffff772187d in glutMainLoop () from /usr/lib/libglut.so.3
No symbol table info available.
#19 0x00000000004017b3 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe6e8) at test.cpp:110
No locals.
(gdb) list 75
70         glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
71         glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
72         glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
73         
74         // Draw a textured quad
75         glBegin(GL_QUADS);
76         glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
77         glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(0, tex_width, 0);
78         glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(tex_height, tex_width, 0);
79         glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(tex_height, 0, 0);
(gdb)
```

Comment: try add parameters -W -Wall for more info...

Answer (score 0):

Beware using `GL_QUADS` it supporting now depends on your OpenGL version. Try first fixing the OpenGL version you use and see what happens next.

```
glutInitContextVersion(3, 3);
glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
```

3.3 is an example. Indeed I am not sure `GL_QUADS` exists for this implementation version.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works

```
glewExperimental=true;
GLenum err=glewInit();
if(err!=GLEW_OK)
{
   //Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong.
   fprintf(stderr, "glewInit failed, aborting.\n");
}


#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GL/glext.h"
#include "GL/glu.h"
#include "GL/freeglut.h"

#include <cstdio>

uint16_t tex_width = 75;
uint16_t tex_height = 24;

GLuint texture;

void display(void)
{
   glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
   glViewport(0, 0, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH), glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT));

   glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT/* | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT*/);

   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glPushMatrix();
   glLoadIdentity();
   glOrtho(0.0, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH), 0.0, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT), -1.0, 1.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glPushMatrix();

   glLoadIdentity();

   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

   // Draw a textured quad
   glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
   glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
   glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(0, tex_width, 0);
   glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(tex_height, tex_width, 0);
   glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(tex_height, 0, 0);
   glEnd();


   glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   glPopMatrix();


   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glPopMatrix();

   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);


   glutSwapBuffers();
}


void render_texture()
{
   GLuint framebuffer = 0;

   glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
   glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

   glGenTextures(1, &texture);

   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, tex_width, tex_height, 0, GL_RGBA,
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

   glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
   GLenum draw_buffers[1] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
   glDrawBuffers(1, draw_buffers);

   if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
   {  
      fprintf(stderr, "[render_texture] Fehler im Framebuffer\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
   glViewport(0, 0, tex_width, tex_height);

   glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f);

   glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
   glVertex2f(0.f,0.f);
   glVertex2f(tex_width, 0.0f);
   glVertex2f(tex_width, (GLfloat)tex_height/2.f);
   glVertex2f(tex_width-(GLfloat)tex_height/2.f, tex_height);
   glVertex2f(0, tex_height);
   glEnd();
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

   glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutInitContextVersion(3, 1);
   glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE/* | GLUT_DEPTH*/);
   glutInitWindowSize(1024, 1024);
   glutCreateWindow("texture test");
   glutDisplayFunc(display);

   glewExperimental=true;
   GLenum err=glewInit();
   if(err!=GLEW_OK)
   {
      //Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong.
      fprintf(stderr, "glewInit failed, aborting.\n");
   }

   render_texture();


   glutMainLoop();
}
```